# iPhone UITableView - action on accessory click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to link the click of an accessory button in a `UITableView` to a method in a particular class. The accessory is on multiple cells, created in code, and thus I can't just do a simple link in interface builder like I am used to.

How do I link an accessory arrow (from the end of a cell in a `UITableView`) to a method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out the `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method on the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: This method is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer valid, Xcode flags a warning it is now depreiated;

WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: in .  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

Comment: Can't reproduce this. It's not marked as deprecated in the [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html](iOS developer-class-reference) and I got new warning in Monodevelop (2.8.6.5, MonoTouch 5.2.5, Xcode 4.2.1) either...

Comment: I concur with @chiffre. [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't list `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` as depreciated.

Comment: It's *Tapped*, not *Type*